# How to overload operator >> to enter vector values of a class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, outofrangeexception

I am trying to find a way to let the user define the length of an int vector, which is a private member of a class, and then insert all of the numbers through the console, however, I did not find any overload specifically made for vectors. Here is my code, which gets: "exception: std::out_of_range at memory location." when it reached the for loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class List
{
private:
    vector<int> numbers;
public:
    List(){vector<int> numbers = {};}
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& i, const List& l);
};

istream& operator>>(istream& i, const List& l)
{
    int help{ 0 };
    i >> help;  //I used help to define the amount of numbers to be added
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < help; i++) //exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 
        i >> l.numbers.at(i);
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    List list;
    cin >> list;
    return 0;
}
```

I've removed operator<< to decrease the code, if you need it, I will send it. Any help, solution or link to the place, where I can learn how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 int help{ 0 };
    i >> help;  //I used help to define the amount of numbers to be added
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < help; i++) //exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 
        i >> l.numbers.at(i);
    return i;
```

Will most definitely cause an out-of-range exception. The `std::vector` is empty, so it will set the element at `i` (which is out of range) to something. Also, the `i` in the loop overshadows the `std::istream` `i`.

You can change that to this:

```
 int help{ 0 };
    i >> help;  //I used help to define the amount of numbers to be added
    l.numbers.resize(help);
    for (int counter{ 0 }; counter < help; counter++) //exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 
        i >> l.numbers.at(counter);
    return i;
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work the best for me, however, only if my vector<int> numbers is public, else I am getting an error that numbers is not accessible. Would you know a fix for this?

Comment: Yes. The reason is because the overloaded operatorio is not part of the class, hence it cannot access private members. Research on friends, it should help you with this problem

Answer (score 0):

- You have to add element before reading there, or read value and add element having the value after that.
- Your `i` used as the loop variable is shadowing the stream `i`. You have to give another name to eithor one of them.
- Updating the vector `l.numbers` means to modify the object `l`, so you cannot mark the object as `const`.

Try this:

Add element before reading:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, List& l)
{
    int help{ 0 };
    is >> help;  //I used help to define the amount of numbers to be added
    l.numbers.resize(help); // create help elements
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < help; i++)
        is >> l.numbers.at(i);
    return is;
}
```

Read value and add element:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, List& l)
{
    int help{ 0 };
    is >> help;  //I used help to define the amount of numbers to be added
    l.numbers.clear(); // remove all elements
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < help; i++)
    {
        int value;
        is >> value; // read value
        l.numbers.push_back(value); // add the value
    }
    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector::at` does not allocate memory. It assumes that the index is valid. Hence, you get the exception.

You can:

1. Use `std::vector::push_back`, or
2. Resize the object first and then use use `std::vector::at`.

#### Option 1

```
for (int i{ 0 }; i < help; i++)
     i >> l.numbers.push_back(i);
```

#### Option 2

```
l.numbers.resize(help);
for (int i{ 0 }; i < help; i++)
     i >> l.numbers.at(i);
```